# Is it realistic for a dedicated server to send out many requests per second?

Tags: networking, max, scalability

***TL;DR***

Is it appropriate for a (dedicated) web server to be **sending** many requests out to other servers every second (naturally with permission from said server)?

---

I'm asking this purely to save myself spending a long time implementing an idea that won't work, as I hope that people will have some more insight into this than me.

I'm developing a solution which will allow clients to monitor the status of their server. I need to constantly (24/7) obtain more recent logs from these servers. Unfortunately, I am limited to getting the last *150 entries* to their logs. This means that for busy clients I will need to poll their servers more.

I'm trying to make my solution scalable so that if it gets a number of customers, I won't need to concern myself with rewriting it, so my benchmark is *1000 clients*, as I think this is a realistic upper limit.

If I have 1000 clients, and I need to poll their servers every, let's give it a number, two minutes, I'm going to be sending requests off to more than 8 servers every second. The returned result will be on average about 15,000 characters, however it could go more or less.

Bearing in mind this server will also need to cope with clients visiting it to see their server information, and thus will need to be lag-free.

Some optimisations I've been considering, which I would probably need to implement relatively early on:

- Only asking for 50 log items. If we find one already stored (They are returned in chronological order), we can terminate. If not, we throw out another request for the other 100. This should cut down traffic by around 3/5ths.
- Detecting which servers get more traffic and requesting their logs less commonly (i.e. if a server only gets 10 logged events every hour, we don't want to keep asking for 150 every few minutes)

I'm basically asking if sending out this many requests per second is considered a **bad thing** and whether my future host might start asking questions or trying to throttle my server. I'm aiming to go shared for the first few customers, then if it gets popular enough, move to a dedicated server.

I know this has a slight degree of opinion enabled, so I fear that it might be a candidate for closure, but I do feel that there is a definite degree of factuality required in the answer that should make it an okay question.

I'm not sure if there's a networking SE or if this might be more appropriate on SuperUser or something, but it feels right on SO. Drop me a comment ASAP if it's not appropriate here and I'll delete it and post to a suggested new location instead.

Comment: Why are you limited to 150 log items?

Comment: Transfer limitation. I can obtain a saved log file from the server that goes back as far as the last time they manually deleted it, but unlike the live logs I can obtain, the format of the file varies massively between clients and so I can't parse it unless I write a dedicated parser for each client (Out of the question)

Comment: I understand it right when i assume you want to write this in PHP?

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET for this project.

Comment: a bit late - but for what its worth, because you are using ASP.Net, sending that many outgoing requests will likely lead to a bottleneck with your connection pool. Refer the 'Connections' section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647786.aspx#scalenetchapt10_topic9) to tune your connection pool.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the input! I'm hoping to integrate log pushing but for the time being I've had to stay with the query approach. I'll definitely consider trying to cut down on the number of simultaneous requests with that knowledge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read about the [C10K Problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html). The article compares several I/O strategies. A certain number of threads that each handle several connections using nonblocking I/O is the best approach imho.

Regarding your specific project I think it is a bad idea to poll for a limited number of log items. When there is a peak in log activity you will miss potentially critical data, especially when you apply your optimizations.

It would be way better if the clients you are monitoring pushed their new log items to your server. That way you won't miss something important.

I am not familiar with the performance of ASP.NET so I can't answer if a single dedicated server is enough. Especially because I do not know what the specs of your server are. Using a reasonable strong server it should be possible. If it turns out to be not enough you should distribute your project across multiple servers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) I'll look into setting up the log pushing for definite! Thanks for the idea.